# NUnit test Bug? Expected <MyType> But was <MyType>

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

```
[Test]
public void testMultiplication()
{
    var five=new Dollar(5);
    Assert.AreEqual(new Dollar(10), five.times(2));
    Assert.AreEqual(new Dollar(15), five.times(3));
}
```

Dollar class

```
public class Dollar
{
    private int amount;

    public Dollar(int amount)
    {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public Dollar times(int multiplier)
    {
        return new Dollar(amount * multiplier);
    }

    public bool equals(Object theObject)
    {
       Dollar dollar = (Dollar) theObject;

       return amount == dollar.amount;
    }
}
```

On line  Assert.AreEqual(new Dollar(10), five.times(2)); test fail with error:

Expected: TDDbooks.Dollar

But was:  TDDbooks.Dollar

Comment: aside: why don't you implement operator overloading?

Comment: Looks like it could be an assembly versioning issue; is it possible that you have two versions of the assembly that implements `TDDbooks.Dollar` loaded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NUnit displays string representation of objects. In order to have handy output, you should override `ToString` method of `Dollar` class:

```
public override string ToString()
{
   return "$" + amount;
}
```

Now output will be like:

```
Expected: $10 
But was: $10
```

Next problem is dollars comparison. NUnit compare objects by calling `Equals` method (not `equals`, but `Equals`. Kent Beck uses Java in his examples. In C# we have Pascal naming for methods). Default implementation of `Equals` method return true if objects have same reference. But in `Times` method you create new instance of `Dollar` class. In order to fix that, you should change `Equals` method implementation to compare amount field.

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{ 
  Dollar other = obj as Dollar;
  if (other == null)
    return false;  

  return amount == other.amount;
}
```

Also notice, that you should use `override` keyword for overriding base class functionality. And one more thing - when you are overriding `Equals` functionality, you should override `GetHashCode` method. In your case it's OK to have something like:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
  return amount.GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: Also, if you plan not to derive from the `Dollar` class, consider making it `sealed`. If you don't make it `sealed`, consider saying `if (GetType() != other.GetType()) return false;` inside the `Equals` method. Otherwise, you could get bad result if `other` is a `Dollar` of a more derived type, like a `DescriptionDollar`.

Answer (score 11):

The `Assert.AreEquals` method will use the `Equals` method to test equality.  Instead of overriding `Object.Equals` the `Dollar` type just defines a new `equals` method that doesn't participate in .Net object equality.  Hence it's not used and the test uses reference equality which fails.  To fix this you need to override the `Object.Equals` method

```
public override bool Equals(object obj) { 
  Dollar other = obj as Dollar;
  if (other == null) {
    return false;
  }

  return amount == other.amount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things:

1. You've defined a new method `equals`, instead of overriding the base class method `Equals`. Switch to overriding and NUnit will call your method.
2. NUnit prints out the object using its `ToString`, and the default implementation of ToString is to simply print the class name. Override `ToString` to print the amount and the assertion message will make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asserting there is that `new Dollar(10)` is the same object as the one `five.times(2)` returns, which is not true.

If you want to assert in that way you'd need to overload the Equals method in your Dollar class like this:

```
 public override bool Equals(Object obj)
 {
     if (obj is Dollar)
     {
         return this.Amount == ((Dollar)obj).Amount;
     }
     return false;
 }
```

You are not using the `override` keyword in your `Equals` method.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution has already been given by a few people, but there's an alternative that might work in other situations.  You'd need to add a getter for the `amount` field like so:

```
public int Amount { get { return amount; } }
```

And then when you do the unit test, it would look like:

```
Assert.AreEqual(10, five.times(2).Amount);
```

So now you're comparing an `int` to another `int`.  Alternatively you could make the `amount` variable public, though that breaks encapsulation.  Obviously using the `Equals` method properly is the better way to go in this case, but in some situations, this might be preferable.